# is it possible to scrape data in browser console using javascript

Tags: javascript

Using browser console following javascript one liner gives you HTML document title.

```
window.document.title
```

How would I go about picking up other HTML element? for example "Questions" from the stackoverflow menu item via browser console - how do I do that? I don't wish to use any other external library just plain javascript.

Comment: do u mean to list all elements  on page? or you want to select perticular element on page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all elements on page by using

```
window.document.getElementsByTagName("*")
```

For stack overflow Questions button, use

```
window.document.getElementById("nav-questions")
```

> You should see [jquery functions and javascript equivalents](https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/selectors/) and [xahlee's list](http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html), along with [javascript info article](https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom).

Answer (score 0):

short answer, yes.

if using Chrome, in console (SHIFT+CTRL+J) type `window.document.` and a dropdown list of elements will appear.

`window.document.location`, for example

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much how you would write the function in a text editor, either copy it over from there to the console or use Shift+Enter to use multi-line commands.

**document.getElementsByClassName** and **document.getElementById** are your friends for this.